# Checking String length returns NullPointerException?

Tags: java, string

For some reason, I am getting a NullPointerException upon checking a String length in an 'if' statement. I am probably doing it wrong, but I wouldn't really know. What the code I am trying to write basically just changes a button's label, but only if the String 'label1' is 0 characters long (or not set), so that it can only be changed once.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

         public class Class1 {

public static String label1;


public static String one = ("Hello");
public static String two = ("Goodbye");

public static void main(String args[]) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    JButton button = new JButton();


    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
            if(label1.length() == 0) {

                label1 = one;
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                button.setText(label1);
            }
            if(label1.length() < 0) {

                label1 = two;
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                button.setText(label1);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }       
    });

    frame.setSize(350, 350);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.add(pane);
    pane.add(button);


     }

 }
```

Comment: You never initialized the `label1` String.

Comment: initialize your label1 before use it.public static String label1=null;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static String label1;
```

to use the line   `if(label1.length() == 0) {` you have to intialize `lable1` before

You are not intialised  lable! anywhere any using it

Try to change that line

```
public static String label="";
```

or add extra null condition

```
if(label1 != null && label1.length() == 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I thought a String would be labeled as containing 0 characters if it was not initialized, but I guess not.

Comment: @NoneNone Glad to help you out.Please mark it as answer (green tick beneath voting arrow)if you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assign some string value to `label`

```
public static String label1 = new String("someString");
```

We get `NullPointerException` when calling some method on an object reference which has not been assigned any object yet and the reference which is erferring to `null`

Answer (score 0):

label1 is null because you didn't initialize it.

label1 = "";

should fix your problem (it will be non-null size 0)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the String object "label1" is not initialized and NULL. This means, if you try to call a method on a non-existing object, the `NullPointerException` must happen.

To check if there is an Object assigned, try `if (label1 != null)`.

To assign a value, do `label1 = "my String"` - this initializes the String object.

Answer (score 0):

Always check for `null`. For example:

```
if(label != null && label.length() > 0) {...}
```

Out of interest, when is `(label1.length() < 0)` ever true?

Comment: It's never true, I have yet to finish writing the entire program.

Comment: Quite. I'm intrigued as to how the need ever arose.